# Displaying a chart in Vaadin 7 with Google Visualization API

Tags: java, javascript, google-visualization, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to display a barchart with the Google Visualization API.
I followed the example code in this thread: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2971952/

Here is my code:

GVis.java

```
@JavaScript({
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js",
        "gvis.js",
        "gvis-connector.js" })
public class GVis extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {}
```

gvis.js

```
var gvis = gvis || {};

gvis.GVis = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.element.innerHTML = "<div id='chart_div' style='height:500px; width:500px;'></div>";

    var oldDocumentWrite = document.write;

    // change document.write temporary
    document.write = function(node) {
        $("body").append(node);
    };

    $(function() {
        window.initialize = function() {

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.write = oldDocumentWrite;
            }, 100);

            function drawVisualization() {

                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        [ 'Year', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Denmark', 'Greece' ],
                        [ '2003', 1336060, 400361, 1001582, 997974 ],
                        [ '2004', 1538156, 366849, 1119450, 941795 ],
                        [ '2005', 1576579, 440514, 993360, 930593 ],
                        [ '2006', 1600652, 434552, 1004163, 897127 ],
                        [ '2007', 1968113, 393032, 979198, 1080887 ],
                        [ '2008', 1901067, 517206, 916965, 1056036 ] ]);

                // Create and draw the visualization.
                new google.visualization.BarChart(document
                        .getElementById("chart_div")).draw(data, {
                    title : "Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
                    width : 100,
                    height : 100,
                    vAxis : {
                        title : "Year"
                    },
                    hAxis : {
                        title : "Cups"
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload=%7B%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22visualization%22%2C%22version%22%3A%221%22%2C%22packages%22%3A%5B%22corechart%22%2C%22table%22%5D%7D%5D%7D&'
                + 'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
};
```

gvis-connector.js

```
window.com_andrebruch_chartframework_chartapis_googlecharts_GVis = function() {
    var gVis = new gvis.GVis(this.getElement());

    this.onStateChange = function() {};
};
```

The code loads this two files:

ui+de,table+de.css

```
<link href="https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/dee027d0b48a2e0a0a0375d00d7dd635/ui+de,table+de.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

format+de,default+de,ui+de,table+de,corechart+de.I.js

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/dee027d0b48a2e0a0a0375d00d7dd635/format+de,default+de,ui+de,table+de,corechart+de.I.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But the chart doesn't appear and there are no JS exceptions.

I am using Vaadin 7.2.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check if all required java script files are in the html header?

Comment: where did you place the files "gvis.js", "gvis-connector.js" ?

Comment: @d2k2 The files are in a source folder under the package `com.andrebruch.chartframework.chartapis.googlecharts`, like GVis.java.

Comment: @d2k2 all required javascript files are at the end of the <body>-tag. If I insert them in the head there is no improvement.

Answer (score -1):

Only my suggestion: Try to use this addon:

https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/visualizationsforvaadin

Javascript it`s cool! but use Java code when you're working in your Vaadin's UIs! Great Framework!

Good luck!